# PHP is not showing my $name in html look

Tags: php

Hello this is my script

```
{
$ign = file_get_contents("LINK.com={$name}");
echo '<div> class="alert alert-success"><b> $name </b> has the in game name: 
$ign </div>';
}
```

The problem is that the script won't show me the generated $name & $ign
it just gives me the $name & $ign not what i wanted like
$ign would be in game name this is because of the html but i dont get it how should it be to make it working?
Sorry this is my first post and I am new to php.

Thanks for taking a look and maybe even answering.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: WTF is `"LINK.com={$name}"`? This is not even a valid URL...

Comment: I'd ask you to write your question better, I didn't understand a thing about what is going on and what is that you want.

Comment: Assuming it works, single quotes in PHP string won't parse variables inside it, only double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you.

First of all take a look at this line. Something does not look right here. I believe it is the = operator that is wrong.

```
$ign = file_get_contents("LINK.com={$name}")
```

I assume you are using ign.com's API because LINK.com does not supply anything for games. Also maybe you could try this.

```
$ign = file_get_contents("LINK.com/{$name}")
```

Change this

```
echo '<div> class="alert alert-success"><b> $name </b> has the in game name: 
$ign </div>';
```

To this

```
echo '<div> class="alert alert-success"><b>'.$name.'</b> has the in game name: 
'.$ign.' </div>';
```

Also is your `<div> class="alert alert-success">` meant to be as it is or does that class go inside the div like so. `<div class="alert alert-success">`

So result would be something like this. Not sure why you would call the $ign variable inside that echo like that but for each their own.

```
{
$ign = file_get_contents("LINK.com/{$name}");
echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><b>'.$name.' </b> has the in game name: '.$ign.' </div>';
}
```

Comment: Blindly assuming `file_get_contents("LINK.com={$name}");` returns something useful.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, Agree, I think he just replaced his own URL with a dummy URL to protect his privacy so my answer is based on IF his `LINK.com={$name}` returns something useful to start with.

Comment: `LINK.com` can be a dummy link. `={$name}` just don't make sense. That's my point.

Comment: No I agree its a bit weird, I have seen something like `={$name}` before but not with =. If its was something like `file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}")` I would understand a bit more but the = throws me off a bit.

Comment: The '.$ign.' was the solution! Thank you so much! and yes it was an api but i forgot to tell... I'm new and dont knwo how to ask the question with all information. But you solved it. THNX

Comment: @ToxicBytez, Its no problem, Just remember the next time you ask a question please supply all the information so everyone can help you, Supplying the API helps greatly in conditions like this because it could be something wrong with the API and not your script. Bottom line always good to supply all information.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code with this.

```
$ign = file_get_contents("LINK.com={".$name."}");
echo '<div> class="alert alert-success"><b> '.$name.' </b> has the in game name: 
'.$ign.' </div>';
```

Comment: Where did you ever see an URL like `something.com={foo}` working?

Comment: you can also do it by using  something.com={$name}

Comment: What are you talking about, that wasn't even my question! I asked where did you ever saw an URL like it working!